# Integral inequality related to the (mixed?) moments of two functions

Tags: inequalities, integration, moments

For $k\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and $t\in [0,1]$ we set

$$
S_{k}(t) = \{(t_1,\ldots, t_k)\colon 1\ge t\ge t_1\ge\ldots\ge t_k\ge 0\}.
$$

Let $a$ and $b$ be two continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Introduce

$$
I_4 = \int_0^1\left[\iint_{S_4(t)}a(t_1)a(t_2)b(t_3)b(t_4)\right]dt + \int_0^1\left[\iint_{S_4(t)}b(t_1)b(t_2)a(t_3)a(t_4)\right]dt,
$$
$$
I_3 =\int_0^1\left[\int_{0}^t a(t_1)\right]dt \cdot\int_0^1\left[\iint_{S_3(t)}a(t_1)b(t_2)b(t_3)\right]dt + \int_0^1\left[\int_{0}^t b(t_1)\right]dt \cdot\int_0^1\left[\iint_{S_3(t)}b(t_1)a(t_2)a(t_3)\right]dt
$$
$$
I_2 =\int_0^1\left[\iint_{S_2(t)}a(t_1)a(t_2)\right]dt \cdot \int_0^1\left[\iint_{S_2(t)}b(t_1)b(t_2)\right]dt
$$
The question is to show the inequality $I_4 - I_3 + I_2\ge 0$.

**Thoughts.** For a function $g$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ we have
$$
\iint_{S_n(t)}g(t_1)\ldots g(t_n)dt_1\ldots dt_n = \frac{1}{n!}\left(\int_0^t g(t_1)\,dt_1\right)^n.
$$
If we introduce $A(t) =\int_0^t a(t_1)\,dt_1$ then we can deduce
$$
\iint_{S_2(t)}a(t_1)a(t_2)dt_1dt_2 = \frac{A(t)^2}{2},
$$
hence the integral $I_2$ can be rewritten in terms of $A$ and $B$.

When $a = b$, similarly to the above calculation, we get
$$
I_4 = \frac{1}{12}\int_0^1 A^4(t)\,dt,
\\ 
I_3 = \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 A(t)dt \cdot \int_0^1 A^3(t)dt,
\\
I_2 = \frac{1}{4} \left(\int_0^1 A(t)^2dt\right)^2.
$$
Consequently
$$
I_4 - I_3 + I_2 = \frac{1}{24}\int_0^1\int_0^1(A(x) - A(y))^4\,dx\,dy \ge 0.
$$
I believe that something similar happens is general situation too.

Comment: There seem to be several typos in your definition of $S_n(t)$.

Comment: There are also seem to be typos in the definition of $I_3$. Can you check everything really well?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I think now everything is ok.