# Taylor coefficients of the integral of the ordered exponential

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, integration, moments, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ be a continuous $2\times 2$ matrix-valued function on $[0,1]$. Define $X_A$ as the solution of
$$
X_A'(t) = A(t) X_A(t), \qquad X(0) = I.
$$
In other words $X_A$ is the ordered exponential of $A$. Assume that $A$ is symmetric with zero trace: $A = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}a & b \\ b & -a\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, where $a$ and $b$ are two continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Define the function $F$ and its Taylor coefficients $\{a_n\}$ by
$$
F(s) = \det\left(\int_0^1X_{sA}(t)X_{sA}^{T}(t)\,dt\right) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_ns^n.
$$
One can see that $a_{n}= 0$ when $n$ id odd.

**Conjecture.** For every $n\ge 0$ the inequality $a_n\ge 0$ holds. **{Conjecture failed, coefficients starting from $a_8$ can attain negative values for piecewise constants functions $A(t)$.}**

**Diagonal case.** When $A = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & -a\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, we have
$$
X_{sA}(t) = \exp\left(s\int_0^t A(x)dx\right) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{s\int_0^t a(x)dx} & 0
\\
0 & e^{-s\int_0^t a(x)dx}
\end{pmatrix},
\\
F(s) = \int_0^1 e^{2s\int_0^t a(x)dx}\,dt\cdot \int_0^1 e^{-2s\int_0^t a(x)dx}\,dt.
$$
If we define $g(t) = 2\int_0^t a(x)dx$ then
$$
F(s) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^ms^{k + m}}{k! m!}\int_0^1g^k(x)dx  \int_0^1g^m(x)dx,
\\
a_n = \sum_{l =0}^n\frac{(-1)^l}{l!(n - l)!} \int_0^1g^{n-l}(x)dx  \int_0^1g^l(x)dx = \frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1\int_0^1(g(x) - g(y))^n\,dx\,dy.
$$
Therefore $a_n = 0$ for odd $n$ and $a_n\ge 0$ for even $n$. In particular,
$$
a_2 = \int_0^1 g^2(x)\,dx -  \left(\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx\right)^2 = Var(g).
$$
In fact, one can see that $F$ is a moment generating function of a random value of the form $X_1 - X_2$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid with the law $g$. Similar argument works also when $A(t) = a(t)M$ with constant matrix $M$.

**First coefficient in the general case.** Ordered exponential admits the following representation:
\begin{gather}
    \label{explicit representaion ordered exponent}
    X_A(t) = I + \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\int_0^t A(t_1) \int_0^{t_1} A(t_2)\int_0^{t_2}\ldots \int_0^{t_{m - 1}} A(t_m)\, dt_m\,\ldots dt_3\,dt_2\, dt_1.
\end{gather}
This gives
$$
a_0 = 1, \qquad a_2 = Var(g_a) + Var(g_b).
$$
Further coefficients are expressed as a sums of multidimensional integrals, for example for $n = 4$ the integral from [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464776/integral-inequality-related-to-the-mixed-moments-of-two-functions) shows up.

**Weaker question.** Is it true that $F(1)\ge 1 + a_2$?

This is what I actually need, but it doesn't seem much easier. The inequality $F(1)\ge 1$ follows from the Minkowski determinant inequality:
$$
\sqrt{\det\left(\int_0^1X_{A}(t)X_{A}^{T}(t)\,dt\right)} \ge \int_0^1\sqrt{\det (X_{A}(t)X_{A}^{T}(t))}\,dt = 1,
$$
because for every $t\ge 0$,$\;$ $\det X_A(t) = \exp\left(\int_0^t\text{trace}A(x)\,dx\right) = 1$.

**UPD.** For every matrix valued function $Y$ on $[0,1]$ the follwing equality holds:
$$
\det\left(\int_0^1Y(x)\,dx\right) = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \left[\det(Y(x) + Y(y)) - \det Y(x) - \det Y(y)\right]\,dx\,dy.
$$
Substitute $Y = X_{sA}X_{sA}^T$. We have $\det Y(t) = 1$ for all $t\ge 1$ hence
$$
F(s) = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \det(Y(x) + Y(y))\,dx\,dy - 2 = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \det(X_{sA}(x)X_{sA}(x)^T + X_{sA}(y)X_{sA}(y)^T) \,dx\,dy - 2
= \int_0^1\int_0^1 \det(I + X_{sA}(x,y)X_{sA}(x,y)^T) \,dx\,dy - 2,
$$
where $X_{sA}(x,y) = X_{sA}^{-1}(x)X_{sA}(y)$ -- the ordered exponent on the segment $[x,y]$. Using the relation $\det (I + M) = 1 + \det(M) + \text{trace} M$ we get
$$
F(s) = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \text{trace}(X_{sA}(x,y)X_{sA}(x,y)^T) \,dx\,dy = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \|X_{sA}(x,y)\|_2^2 \,dx\,dy,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is a Frobenius norm.

**UPD2.** I've written python code to draw a plot of $F(s)$ for some random piecewise constant matrices $A(t)$. All of the plots look like this:

[image]

It is always increasing and convex.

Comment: (I think you mean  $r=0$ in the Peano-Barker formula for the transition matrix)